# How do I convert a date ( YYYY-MM-DD ) into a month number in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, date

I got a table:

```
CREATE TABLE TRANSACTION ( 
transaction_date date,
id_transaction int,
PRIMARY KEY (id_transaction)
);
```

and I want to compare the month of 'transaction_date' field with a number of month.

```
SELECT *
FROM TRANSACTION T 
WHERE month = transaction_date;
```

but I don't know how to make this conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transaction_date)`

```
SELECT * 
FROM transaction
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transaction_date) = 1;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/82de0/1)</kbd>

As per the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html):

**EXTRACT (field FROM source)**

> The extract function retrieves subfields such as year or hour from
>   date/time values. source must be a value expression of type timestamp,
>   time, or interval.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM TRANSACTION T 
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIMESTAMP transaction_date) = month;
```

`month` should be an integer between 1 (January) and 12 (December).